# Jquery Circle progress bar value more than 100%

Tags: jquery, progress-bar, geometry

I'm working on a jQuery circle progress bar with reference of Circlefuljs (https://github.com/pguso/jquery-plugin-circliful). Everything works fine in this plugin, but in some scenarios my percentage reaches more than 100%. If the percentage value is 120% the circle is filled fully for its 100% and it seems to be overlapped with the same color for the next 20%. In this case, from the end user point of view, they cant see the variation and it seems to be confusing. So I need some variation to show that extra 20% in some different colors are some other things. Here is my snippet I tried with https://jsfiddle.net/heh12u5v/7/

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/circliful/1.0.2/js/jquery.circliful.min.js"></script>
<div style="width:400px">
    <div id="test-circle"></div>
</div>

var value = 120
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#test-circle").circliful({
    animationStep: 5,
    foregroundBorderWidth: 15,
    backgroundBorderWidth: 15,
    percent: value,
  });
});
```

I don't know whether my question is right or not, but I face this scenario. Is there any possible way to do this so that extra 20% percent shows with a thin line with some color? If any thing please suggest it to me. It will be very helpful for me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: In percent you have set 120. if you need 100% then only set value as 100

Comment: have you ever seen a 120% pie ?its like an old russian joke about % of  alcohol in vodka :))

Comment: a solution will be to change the circle into a bar or to use 2 circles

Comment: in short percent value should be less then 100

Comment: @ButaniVijay I can understand the percentage value should be less than 100 only, In some scenario in my use case the percentage reaches more than 100 percent that's why i came to question

Comment: then you should manage it using if condition and check value is more then 100 percent or not

Comment: an idea https://jsfiddle.net/heh12u5v/9/

Comment: Thanks @ButaniVijay I will take you idea and I will see what i can see with it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes things are not as tidy as you imagine..

```js
var value = 120
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#test-circle").circliful({
    animationStep: 5,
    foregroundBorderWidth: 15,
    backgroundBorderWidth: 15,
    percent: value,
  });
  
  if(value > 100){
    var extra = value - 100;
    $("#test-circle-time").circliful({
      animationStep: 5,
      foregroundBorderWidth: 0,
      backgroundBorderWidth: 0,
      percent: 100,
      percentageTextSize:0
    },function(){
     $("#test-circle-extra").circliful({
        animationStep: 5,
        foregroundBorderWidth: 8,
        backgroundBorderWidth: 8,
        percent: extra,
        backgroundColor: "none",
        foregroundColor:'#a33',
        percentageTextSize:0
      });
    });
  }
});
```

```css
#circle-container{
  postition:relative;
}
#circle-container > div{
 position:absolute;
 top:0;
 left:0;
 width:200px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/circliful/1.0.2/js/jquery.circliful.min.js"></script>
<div id="circle-container">
  <div id="test-circle"></div>
  <div id="test-circle-time"></div>
  <div id="test-circle-extra"></div>
</div>
```

what we did was if the value is greater than 100, we add another circle that runs at the same time, is invisible, and only goes to 100.  This allows us to know when the first circle reaches 100%.  Then when 100 is reached we add a 3rd thinner one for the remaining value.

In this way:

1. We keep the percentage counting smoothly from 0 to 120%
2. We have the "extra" start exactly when the percent passes 100%

Yes.

Comment: Thank you so much Very neat explanation

Answer (score 2):

Hi please check out this solution : [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/heh12u5v/11/)
(i have modified @madalin ivascu jsfiddle). may be you want some think like below.

Javascript:

```
var value = 120; // here your dynamic value
var extravalue=0;
if(value>100)
{
    extravalue=value-100;
  value=100;
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#test-circle").circliful({
    animationStep: 5,
    foregroundBorderWidth: 15,
    backgroundBorderWidth: 15,
    percent: value
  },function(){
    if(extravalue!=0)
    {
       $("#test-circle2").circliful({
            animationStep: 5,
            foregroundBorderWidth: 15,
            backgroundBorderWidth: 15,
            backgroundColor:"none",
            foregroundColor: '#009900',
            percent: extravalue
        },function(){
            alert("completed");
        });    
    }
  });
});
```

HTML :

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/circliful/1.0.2/js/jquery.circliful.min.js"></script>
<div style="width:400px">
    <div id="test-circle"></div>
  <div id="test-circle2"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The value what your are giving is actually a hard value , if you want to show percentage than you should divide it by some value value like if 120 is out 120 then it should like

```
    var value =  (120/120)*100;
```

else

```
    var value = (120/out_of_value)*100;
```

Comment: The value is not a hard value,The same formula i have used, Consider an example I have today target of selling 30 mobiles(in this case 30 units is the target is 100%) but I have sold 35 mobiles then in this case by your formula
'(35/30)*100' which gives 116.6 some thing so my achieved target is more than the target I set. for this scenario only im asking the variations

Comment: so in this case you shouldn't show value in percentage because , it will more than 100%.